# Java, помогите с security.policy

Tags: java

Мне нужно сделать, чтобы программа могла занимать только один порт, это я сделал с помощью флагов: `-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=server.policy` и в файле `server.policy` написал:

```
grant {
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "127.0.0.1:2565", "connect,accept,resolve";
};
```

Но проблема в том, что такое решение, блокирует доступ ко всему, и только вот это работает. Вариант просто написать всё, что требует программа просто нереален. Учитывая что эта программа (сервер) имеет возможность добовления плагинов, то есть или в файле просто как-то, где-то найти список всего и туда добавить, или же возможно решение по типу разрешить всё, но ограничить java.net.SocketPermission. Ну разрешить всё можно java.security.AllPermission, а Вот как то ограничить, без понятия.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартный [менеджер безопасности](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) действует по принципу "что явно не разрешено, то запрещено", поэтому в политике безопасности вы можете указывать только директиву `grant`. На сколько я понимаю, переписать код сервера вы не можете, поэтому и менеджер безопасности вам не подменить. Остаётся только смотреть чего серверу не хватает при запуске и добавлять в политику. Или искать где-то список необходимых прав.